# alternative to iteruples(), trying to optimise the processing of a json

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

i have some code which converts a json into a dataframe preparing for db insertion. It is working great but is taking a long time, doe to the size of the JSON. I was wondering if i am doing something inefficient that could be optimised?

I have recorded timings for each of the steps and it seems the iteruples section i am using is taking the most time. this is below:

ultimately I have a list of lists, that can contains 3 elements in any order. the match statement is being used to ensure the right data goes in the right column.

```
for row in df_batb.itertuples():
    #print(len(row.h_batb))
    for ladder in row.h_batb:
        match ladder[0]:
            case 0:
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_0_pos'] = ladder[0]
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_0_price'] = ladder[1]
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_0_dep'] = ladder[2]
            case 1:
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_1_pos'] = ladder[0]
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_1_price'] = ladder[1]
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_1_dep'] = ladder[2]
            case 2:
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_2_pos'] = ladder[0]
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_2_price'] = ladder[1]
                df_batb.at[row_count,'b_2_dep'] = ladder[2]
    row_count = row_count +1
```

Any suggestions welcome.

this what h_batb looks like:
h_batb
0 [[2, 2.46, 487.28], [1, 2.48, 469.57], [0, 2.5...
1 [[0, 6.6, 216.8]]
2 [[4, 0, 0]]

Comment: How does `row.h_batb` typically look like?

Comment: example json line:

Comment: {
 "id": "1.201092776",
 "rc": [{
  "batb": [
   [2, 2.46, 487.28],
   [1, 2.48, 469.57],
   [0, 2.5, 301.89]
  ],
  "batl": [
   [1, 2.54, 347.48]
  ],
  "id": 16321155
 }, {
  "batb": [
   [0, 6.6, 216.8]
  ],
  "id": 37243337
 }, {
  "batl": [
   [0, 4.5, 230.42]
  ],
  "id": 25842155
 }]
}

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the readers of
json
only but in
for loop and if statement
Effectively slows down the script
why you don't try to use thread or multiProcess to speed Up

Comment: never used those before, so we review and see if it can help. for context im using a for loop to iterate through each line of the json seperately. json size is 100k+ rows